# How to combine these SQL queries so that it can display one output?

Tags: sql

Help needed to combine the output of this query together.How it can be done??TQ

```
select facility, route, operation, script_id 
from F_ROUTEOPER
where facility = 'A01' and operation in ('6910','7976')
AND src_erase_date is null
and (script_id not in ('PHQ-LOTCHKRV','PHQ-LOTCHK') or script_id is null)  
AND (route NOT LIKE '9EL%' AND route NOT LIKE '9TB%'
AND route NOT LIKE 'BLB%' AND route NOT LIKE 'BWR%' AND route NOT LIKE 'CRL%')


select facility, route, operation, script_id 
from F_ROUTEOPER
where facility = 'A01' and operation in ('6912','7976') 
AND src_erase_date is null
and (script_id not in ('PHQ-LOTCHKRV','PHQ-LOTCHK') or script_id is null)  
AND (route NOT LIKE '9EL%' AND route NOT LIKE '9TB%'
AND route NOT LIKE 'BLB%' AND route NOT LIKE 'BWR%' AND route NOT LIKE 'CRL%')

select facility, route, operation, script_id 
from F_ROUTEOPER
where facility = 'A01' and operation in ('7344','7976') 
AND src_erase_date is null
and (script_id not in ('PHQ-LOTCHKRV','PHQ-LOTCHK') or script_id is null)  
AND (route NOT LIKE '9EL%' AND route NOT LIKE '9TB%'
AND route NOT LIKE 'BLB%' AND route NOT LIKE 'BWR%' AND route NOT LIKE 'CRL%')

select facility, route, operation, script_id 
from F_ROUTEOPER
where facility = 'A01' and operation in ('8344','7976')
AND src_erase_date is null
and (script_id not in ('PHQ-LOTCHKRV','PHQ-LOTCHK') or script_id is null)  
AND (route NOT LIKE '9EL%' AND route NOT LIKE '9TB%'
AND route NOT LIKE 'BLB%' AND route NOT LIKE 'BWR%' AND route NOT LIKE 'CRL%')
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine all the `operation` values in a single IN... i.e.

```
operation in ('6910','7976','6912','7344','8344')
```

Your other conditions are exactly the same.  The full query

```
select facility, route, operation, script_id 
  from F_ROUTEOPER
 where facility = 'A01'
   and operation in ('6910','7976','6912','7344','8344')
   AND src_erase_date is null
   and (script_id not in ('PHQ-LOTCHKRV','PHQ-LOTCHK') or script_id is null)  
   AND (route NOT LIKE '9EL%' AND
        route NOT LIKE '9TB%' AND
        route NOT LIKE 'BLB%' AND
        route NOT LIKE 'BWR%' AND
        route NOT LIKE 'CRL%')
```

Comment: when you think about it, it's a silly question, requiring just a little logic.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword UNION should work just great for you.
Take a look at the documentation here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: tq...i tried it and it worked...

Comment: great. if it is what you needed, can you accept this answer?

Answer (score 1):

The four queries seem to be the same excpet the predicate `AND operation In ..`, you can combine this predicate form the four queries like so:

```
select facility, route, operation, script_id 
from F_ROUTEOPER
where facility = 'A01' and operation in ('6910','7976', '6912', '8344','7976')
...
```

However, you can use `UNION`(implicit distinct or `UNION ALL` to combine the results from different queries if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the values for `operation` in a single `IN`:

```
select facility, route, operation, script_id 
from F_ROUTEOPER
where facility = 'A01' and operation in ('6910','7976', '6912', '7344', '8344') 
    AND src_erase_date is null 
    AND (script_id not in ('PHQ-LOTCHKRV','PHQ-LOTCHK') or script_id is null)  
    AND (route NOT LIKE '9EL%' AND route NOT LIKE '9TB%' AND route NOT LIKE 'BLB%' AND 
         route NOT LIKE 'BWR%' AND route NOT LIKE 'CRL%')
```

Answer (score 0):

if all of the queries have the same number of columns and the same column names and the same datatype then use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table1 
union
select col4 as col1,col5 as col2,col6 as col3 from table 2
```